# Python classes how are unassigned class instances handled?

Tags: python, class, memory-management

Anyone know how code like this is handled?

```
myclass().mymethod()
```

Normally you would assign assign your class to a variable and destroy it later when not needed, in this instance does python run the code and free up the memory after or does it hang around until the program ends?

the above is cleaner and why assign to a variable when you don't need it again? 
thought I would find out before I put code like the above all over my projects. :)

Comment: If you are doing this all over your code... consider making it just a regular function instead, and/or making myclass a module instead of a class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided `myclass().mymethod()` doesn't create additional references to `myclass()` (via the method's `self` argument), once `mymethod()` returns `myclass()` will be removed from memory again.

CPython uses reference counting to track what objects stay around. When you create `myclass()`, the stack holds one reference to it. The interpreter then looks up the `mymethod` attribute, which being a method creates another reference to the `myclass()` object, stored on the method object. The stack holds on to the method object, keeping the method object alive for the next step. The method is then called, which is passing in the object as `self` to the function; that's a 3rd reference.

If the method doesn't add `self` to any other structures (adding `self` or another method on `self` to a global list, for example), then when the method returns, the `self` local name is cleaned up, and the reference count drops to 2. The method itself is no longer needed, it is removed from the stack (which destroys the method object as it now has 0 references) and the reference count for `myclass()` drops to 1. The `myclass()` object is no longer used either, so the count drops to 0, and the instance is removed from memory.

Comment: awesome good explanation, i hoped something like that would be the case :)